# NoClassDefFoundError while running a valid jar (compiled with dependencies) despite having commons-httpclient and httpcomponents dependencies on pom

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to automate a simple user act by using selenium webdriver from main method (not under test scope) 
When running the following code from the complier it works!
But when running the jar on several cases - facing the following issue 
(I'm running on Ubuntu, using java 7)

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager"

@Log
public class MainProgram {

```
public  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

public static void main(String args[]) {
 //   Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new WebModule());

    System.out.println("Browser will soon be opened");
    MainProgram mainProgram = new MainProgram();
    mainProgram.run();

}

public void run(){

    driver.get("http://www.google.co.il");
    WebElement lookFor = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    if(!lookFor.isDisplayed()){
        driver.close();
      log.log(Level.WARNING,"Failed!");
    };
    driver.close();

}

}
```

WebDriver dependencies on pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>

Case A

 when removed -commons-httpclient - received: HttpClientConnectionManager as follows:

<!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
          <!--  <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:77)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case B

removed both commons-httpclient + httpcomponents received HttpClientConnectionManager:

<!--        &lt;!&ndash;
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>&ndash;&gt;

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
          &lt;!&ndash;  <scope>test</scope>&ndash;&gt;
        </dependency>-->


liron@liron-Latitude-3330:~$ java -jar automatic-tests-4.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Try
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Case C
when both were added to pom - same HttpClientConnectionManager


liron@liron-Latitude-3330:~$ java -jar automatic-tests-4.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Browser will soon be opened
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:77)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How are you trying to run the JAR? What's the command you are running?

Comment: Since I'd used - maven-assembly-plugin + <mainClass>seleniumExec.MainProgram</mainClass> (maven-jar-plugin 2.2) I'm running: java -jar automatic-tests-4.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar (no need to run as "java -cp" + name of main class

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ran into this same issue last night with my WebDriver project, and after a bit of debugging, found out that it was missing the following dependency. After adding them I didn't encounter this exception again.

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
       <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.5</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: cool, I only use following (works) -<dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
             <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
             <version>4.3.4</version>
           <!--  <scope>test</scope>-->
         </dependency>

Comment: I don't understand why the webdriver project doesn't include this? Or rather, I would follow @SiKing answer instead and reiterate that one should not need to define those dependencies explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

You should only need `selenium-java` in your pom dependencies. See the [this graphic @ Selenium HQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) which explains how parts of Selenium are related. Further, Selenium itself has dependencies on `httpclient`, you should not need to define those explicitly. If you do have a legitimate need for those, things will collide and you will need to clean that up with `exclusions`.

After you clean up your pom, you can run `mvn dependency:tree` to see what is going on in your project.

Comment: I managed to comment out selenium-api + selenium-server and the project did compiled but while commenting out the firefox driver I'd received - error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist, + I'd commented out the apa-http related and it's fine yet my original issue did not solved :(

Comment: Post the results of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: I can't add it all it's, too long.. the http related jars in the tree are:  under selenium-java: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.2, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.2, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.1 and that is all,

Comment: *UPDATE* I'd deleted some more dependencies which came from the project parent and rebuild, now the browser does open but getting - 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/net/MediaType
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpCommandCodec.encode(JsonHttpCommandCodec.java:197), I'll debug, thanks.

Comment: solved by adding - <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>    WORKS!

Answer (score 3):

Adding new google guava helps in my case:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

That's because other dependencies can download old one guava 18 version.
And of course like **testphreak** said: org.apache.httpcomponents